# Find a polynomial with the smallest degree , with real coefficients such that it is divisable by $x-1$ and $(x-i)^2$ and dividing ..

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a polynomial with the smallest degree , with real coefficients such that it is divisible by $x-1$ and $(x-i)^2$ and dividing by $x+1$ gives a remainder $8$.

Lets say this polynomial is $p(x)$, since it is divisible with $x-1$ and $(x-i)^2$ then it must be of the shape: $p(x)=(x-1)(x-i)^2p_1(x)$ and also because of Complex conjugate root theorem. I know that $x+i$ must also be a root. What I don't know is, since $x-i$ is a root to the second degree, does this mean that $x+i$ is also a root to the second degree?

Either way, I have trouble finishing up, since I have $p(x)=(x-1)(x-i)^2(x+i)p_1(x)$ and $$p(x)=q(x)(x+1)+8$$ how do I go about finding $p(x)$ completely?

Comment: Yes. you must have a factor $z-i$ with multiplicity 2. Let $p(z)=(z-1)(z-i)^2(z+i)^2+k$ and fink $k$.

Comment: yes, it shall also be $(x+i)^2$

Comment: @MyGlasses: did you mean "$+k$" or "$\cdot k$"? Adding $k$ won't work, for it'll ruin the divisibility.

Comment: @JohnHughes You are right. I was hasty. It must be $\times k$.

Comment: Both of these answers are great, I dont know which one to give the points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
p(x) &= k\cdot (x-1) (x-i)^2 (x+i)^2\\
p(x) &= k\cdot (x-1) (x^2+1)^2\\
&= (x+1) q(x) + r
\end{align}
where $r$ is supposed to be $8$. Plugging in $x = -1$ on both sides gives
\begin{align}
 k\cdot (x-1) (x^2+1)^2 &= (x+1) q(x) + 8 \\
 k\cdot (-1-1) ((-1)^2+1)^2 &= (-1+1) q(-1) + 8 \\
 k\cdot (-2) (2)^2 &= 0\cdot q(-1) + 8 \\
 k\cdot (-8) &=  8 \\
 k &= -1.
\end{align}

So 
$$
p(x) = -(x-1)(x^2 + 1)^2.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Note the complex conjugate root theorem needs a conjugate of equal multiplicity:

$$p(x)=(x-1)(x-i)^2(x+i)^2p_1(x)=(x-1)(x^2+1)^2p_1(x)$$

Upon expanding, one may note that

$$(x-1)(x^2+1)^2=x^5-x^4+2x^3-2x^2+x-1=(x+1)(x^4-2x^3+4x^2-6x+7)-8$$

To make the end result $+8$, multiply everything through by $-1$.  That is, $p_1(x)=-1$.

Comment: Having obtained $(x-1)(x^2+1)$ one might note that the remainder theorem, putting $x=-1$, would give $p(-1)=-8p_1(-1)$ as the remainder on division by $x+1$. This saves expanding everything.

Comment: Indeed -- see my answer. :)